# Renew password link has expired

Tags: magento2, password

I have an issue with the reinitialization of the password.
When the user asks to renew the password, he receives the email (until now, all is working).
When he clicks on the button, he access to the website but with the error message "the link has expired" so he cannot update/change his password.
My Magento website is 2.2.7, has not so much installed extensions, and none of them should surcharge the password feature.

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: have you override controller createpassword in your any extension?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Please check once and confirm.

Comment: is there a quick way to check that ?

Comment: Find "createpassword" in your extension.

Comment: No luck.
The only "createPassword" instances that I could find are contained in the default "module-customer" and "magento2-base" vendor directories.

Comment: have you do any functional change related to reset password or add any extension related to it ?

Comment: No, I installed some basic extensions (ERP, rewards, logistics, payment, a theme based on Luma, which do not overwrite this feature) but nothing that should impact the feature.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update **Recovery Link Expiration Period**

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Password Options -> Recovery Link Expiration Period (hours)
```

[image]

Comment: Tried that but no luck.